# Linking to local network files with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

Excel is remarkably bad when it comes to images, while Google Sheets has the `=image(...)` function, which is pretty good, and can be filtered, etc.

I have a local network server which has all the images I require, and I should, in theory, know the exact address for them.

Is there a way (including paying for Google Apps), where I can host my images locally and reference them in preferably locally hosted Google Sheets implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Google Sheets IMAGE built-in function only can access images that are publicly accessible and hosted on web servers.

There is no locally hosted Google Sheets implementation.